# My url parameter says undefined. How can I fix this? (React, Node)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql

I have the following React Component. The componenet has a useEffect function with a get method associated with an axios create function with a baseURL.
I'm having an issue getting the correct url to load on my page. Instead of getting a route such as '/collection/print' to retrieve data from the database I get '/collection/**undefined**'.

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import collectionAPI from '../apis/collectionAPI';
import { CollectionContext } from '../context/collectionContext';
import ItemC from './item';

const CollectionC = (props) => {

    const {product} = useParams();
    const {collection, setCollection} = useContext(CollectionContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async (req, res) => {
            try{
                const response = await collectionAPI.get(`/collection/${product}`);
                setCollection(response.data.data.products);
                console.log(response);
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        }

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return(
        <div>
            <div className="main-body">
                <div className="center subtitle-div">
                    <a className="subtitle-anchor active" href="/collection/comic"><h1 className="subtitle">COMICS</h1></a>
                    <a className="subtitle-anchor" href="/collection/print"><h1 className="subtitle">PRINTS</h1></a>
                    <a className="subtitle-anchor" href="/collection/personal-work"><h1 className="subtitle">PERSONAL</h1></a>
                </div>
                <div className="collection-menu">
                    <ItemC/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CollectionC;
```

I also have the following Node.JS router file. The route I'm experiencing an issue with attempts to get all of a particular product from my PostgreSQL database. If i hard code in the final parameter of the URL either in the React useEffect or database query it works fine but if I make it a variable parameter in both I get undefined.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("../db");

//Get all collection items of a certain type
router.get("/collection/:product", async(req, res) => {

    try{
        const collection = await db.query("SELECT * FROM collection WHERE PRODUCT=$1", [req.params.product]);
        console.log(req.params.product);
        console.log(collection);
        res.status(200).json({
            status: "success",
            results: collection.rows.length,
            data:{
                collection: collection.rows
            }
        })
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

I'm very new to this, so hopefully I've provided enough information to potentially get some help with this issue.

Comment: can you confirm if `useParams();` returns something?

Comment: Firstly, I would suggest putting product in the dependency array. Also, are you accessing the correct route /collection/print and is the URL changing later?

Comment: It seems the useParams(); is not returning anything. I'm trying to get it to grab the :product parameter in the url.
I'm trying to access a variable route "/collection/:product".

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (req, res) => {
        try{
            const response = await collectionAPI.get(`/collection/${product}`);
            setCollection(response.data.data.products);
            console.log(response);
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    fetchData();
}, [product]);  // add product in the array
```